# OpenFileDialog throwing System.IO.FileNotFoundException before it shows the browse dialog

Tags: c#, forms, .net-5

I started creating a simple OpenFileDialog in .NET 5.0,
but I get a
`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Unable to find the specified file.'`  exception before I can even see the browse dialog.

The dialog should open when I click on the `m_FileUploader` button. This is the code I use:

**Main.Designer.cs**

```
  // 
  // m_FileUploader
  // 
  this.m_FileUploader.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(508, 17);
  this.m_FileUploader.Name = "m_FileUploader";
  this.m_FileUploader.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(234, 52);
  this.m_FileUploader.TabIndex = 0;
  this.m_FileUploader.Text = "Browse descr_names.txt";
  this.m_FileUploader.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
  this.m_FileUploader.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.FileUploader_Click);
  // 
  // m_OpenFileDialog
  // 
  this.m_OpenFileDialog.Filter = "Names |*descr_names.txt";
  this.m_OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "Documents";
  this.m_OpenFileDialog.Title = "Open descr_names.txt";
  this.m_OpenFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
```

**Main.cs**

```
  private void FileUploader_Click (Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (m_OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) { // Exception throws here
      // Do stuff with file
    }
  }
```

When I click continue in debug, the rest of the code is executed correctly, but the standalone executable does not like this exception and stops the application.

What am I forgetting here?

Comment: I'm guessing that the folder referenced by `InitialDirectory` is different depending on how you are running the code.

Comment: I guess the same as Neil, could you try to change it into `m_OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";` ?

Comment: @MatthewWatson setting it to `Documents` was the issue. I fixed it by using `Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using different value for `InitialDirectory`, since value `Documents` might not be handled correctly. Instead you should do:

```cs
using System;

// Get path for User's documents folder from .NET
var pathToDocs = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments));
this.m_OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = pathToDocs;
```

See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=net-5.0) for more details about `SpecialFolder`. Or [`InitialDirectory` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.initialdirectory?view=windowsdesktop-5.0).